# Finding the equation for a cagr with yearly production

Tags: functions

I have this scenario:

- Miners produce $500$ per year
- Scientists improve returns by $0.04\%$
  per year
- Calculate the return in 20 years for an amount M of miners $(1-10)$ and $S$ of scientists $(0-9)$. N is years and E, expected return.

I started with this equation (basic CAGR): $E=(M\cdot500)\cdot(1+(0.04\cdot S))^N$ 
This works if the miner only produces once but obviously he does for $20$ years with increased returns each year.

Is there a simple way of writing the right equation or is it something that can only be done easily in something like excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to do this from year to year, and see if there is any logic to write it in general:

In the first year, miners produce $500$, if we have $M$, it is $500*M$. Scientist  improve the return by $0,04%$, but we have $S$, so they improve by $S*0,04%$.

So, for the first year, we have: $(500*M)*(1+(0,04*S)).$

I am not sure I am understanding how we go further, I understood it this way:

For the second year, miners will produce the same like the first year and scientists will improve this with the same amount: $(500*M)*(1+(0,04*S))$ adds up again, but we also had that amount from the first year, so it will be greater  now as well: $[(500*M)*(1+(0,04*S))]*(1+(0,04*S))+(500*M)*(1+(0,04*S))$ for the second year.

You can see the logic, if we go further, it could be written down in this way: For $n$ years, the production is: $$(500*M)*(1+(0,04*S))^n + (500*M)(1+(0,04*S))^{n-1} +...(500*M)(1+(0,04*S))$$

This whole thing can be written down as a sum: $\sum_{k=1}^{n} 500M*(1+(0,04*S))^{k}$. In your case, you have to write $n=20$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23725/discussion-on-answer-by-atvin-finding-the-equation-for-a-cagr-with-yearly-produc).